# Is it possible to handle calculations after didApplyConstraints inside of a Delegating class?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, event-handling, skspritenode, skscene

I made a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` called `JoyStick` that follows the delegate pattern, where its delegate is `GameScene`. In an effort to further clean up the `GameScene`, the `JoyStick` class also implements its own `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` methods.

The problem is that I have some position calculations in the `JoyStick`'s `touchesMoved` method that need to be made after certain `SKConstraints` have been applied to the joystick (such as bounding the joystick handle to the base). I know that there is a `didApplyConstraints` instance method of `SKScene`, and that the documentation indicates that it should be overridden and not called as it is already called once per frame.

However, I'm not sure how to *integrate* `didApplyConstraints` into my delegating joystick class's `touchesMoved` method without resorting to moving logic back into my `GameScene`'s `didApplyConstraints`.

Here is a simplified example of what I currently have implemented with the delegate pattern. Note that the below code allows the variable `joyVector` to take on values outside of the acceptable range because the constraint hasn't yet been applied.

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var shipNode: SKSpriteNode?
    var joyStick: JoyStick?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.view?.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

        // Init the ship
        guard let shipNode = self.childNode(withName: "ShipNode") as? SKSpriteNode else {
            fatalError("Player node not loaded!")
        }
        self.shipNode = shipNode

        // Init the joystick
        joyStick = JoyStick()
        joyStick?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        joyStick?.position = CGPoint(x: -500, y: -200)
        joyStick?.delegate = self
        self.addChild(joyStick!)
    }
}

extension GameScene: JoyStickDelegate{
    var objPhysicsBody: SKPhysicsBody? {
        return self.shipNode?.physicsBody
    }
}
```

**JoyStick.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

protocol JoyStickDelegate: class {
    var objPhysicsBody: SKPhysicsBody? {get}
}

class JoyStick: SKSpriteNode {
    weak var delegate: JoyStickDelegate!

    var joyVector: CGVector = CGVector()
    var handle: SKSpriteNode?

    init () {
        let baseTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "joyStickBase")
        super.init(texture: baseTexture, color: UIColor.clear, size: baseTexture.size())

        // Add the joystick handle onto the base
        handle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "joyStickHandle")
        handle?.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0)

        // Add constraints
        let range = CGFloat(self.size.width/2 - (handle?.size.width)! / 2)
        let moveRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: 0, upperLimit: range)
        let rangeConstraint = SKConstraint.distance(moveRange, to: CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0))
        handle?.constraints = [rangeConstraint]

        self.addChild(handle!)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func moveJoyStick(_ touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        guard let fingerPosition = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        self.handle!.position = fingerPosition
    }

    func getJoyVector(handlePosition: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        return CGVector(dx: handlePosition.x, dy: handlePosition.y)
    }

    func resetJoyStick() {
        delegate?.objPhysicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        //animation to return the joystick to the center...
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.moveJoyStick(touches)
        joyVector = getJoyVector(handlePosition: self.handle!.position)
        delegate?.objPhysicsBody?.velocity = joyVector
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.moveJoyStick(touches)
        joyVector = getJoyVector(handlePosition: self.handle!.position)
        delegate?.objPhysicsBody?.velocity = joyVector
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        resetJoyStick()
    }

    override func touchesEstimatedPropertiesUpdated(_ touches: Set<UITouch>) {}
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {}
}
```

An alternative implementation that did **work correctly** was to keep the touch event methods inside the `JoyStick` class but also drop the delegation pattern all together. Instead, I accessed the `JoyStick` `handlePosition` (as a vector) inside `GameScene` via a `getter` method and applied it as a velocity inside `GameScene`'s `didApplyConstraints` method. Here are the two snippets of added code to make this work:

**Add to JoyStick.swift:**

```
func getPositionVelocity() -> CGVector {
    guard let handlePosition = self.handle?.position else { return CGVector() }
    return CGVector(dx: handlePosition.x, dy: handlePosition.y)
}
```

**Add to GameScene.swift:**

```
...
//joyStick?.delegate = self
...

override func didApplyConstraints() {
    self.shipNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = self.joyStick?.getPositionVelocity() ?? CGVector()
}
```

While this achieves the desired behavior of only applying velocities bounded by the radius of the joystick, it seems far less elegant and greatly reduces the amount of encapsulation/generality that I had with the delegate pattern - which becomes noticeable as the game grows.

Ultimately, is it possible to avoid piling in post-constraint logic into a single `didApplyConstraints` definition in `GameScene` to achieve this functionality? And why is it that `UIResponder` touch events seem to always be handled before `:didApplyConstraints` - even though they seem to be outside of the `SKScene Frame-Cycle`?

Comment: If you looking at the SpriteKit life cycle, and if I understand your question, maybe you can make your "distance calculations" on :update ? that is after the didApplyConstraints, of course on the next render. I don't see the problem there.

Comment: @Maetschl I think that I’d run into the same problem - I have the calculations in the joystick’s touchesMoved method (outside of the GameScene) so I’m not sure how to make sure it’s called on update? I think I’m confused by where touchesMoved actually fits into Frame-Cycle Events like :update or :didApplyConstraints more broadly?

Comment: You can call directly on override update of the scene or in the update timeinterval of your GKComponent if you are using GameplayKit.

Comment: @Maetschl can you please elaborate? I could call the overridden `:update` of the SKScene delegate? I thought that one shouldn't directly call this method as it's called once per frame already? Also, what would calling it from the delegating class's `touchesMoved` do? Would this ensure `didApplyConstraints` was called by the time the `touchesMoved` code is executed?

Comment: don't call `update` directly, on the update method you can call the update of your component and make the calculations.

Comment: @Maetschl the "update" of the `SKSpriteNode` subclass `JoyStick`'s member variables takes place in the its own `:touchesMoved` method. The hope is to encapsulate all of the `:touchesMoved` logic in the `SKSpriteNode` itself and pass the calculated data back to the `SKScene` via delegation. There is a `SKConstraint` on the `JoyStick` but it's not *applied* at the time of `:touchesMoved` calculations are made. The question is whether it's possible to encapsulate everything in the `JoyStick` class or if I have to pass data back and forth to the `SKScene` - just to use its `didApplyConstraints`

Comment: Maybe if you edit your question and add some code I could help you more (please don't paste all code, make a simple example for this purpose)

Comment: @Maetschl I edited the question to include sample code and some further clarification

Answer (score 0):

You have two objects with different methods inside. You can not move both methods into one class directly. 
But it is possible to do in this way:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var onJoysticNeedVerticalPosition: (()-> CGVector)? 
    ....
    override func didApplyConstraints() {
        self.shipNode?.physicsBody?.velocity = onJoysticNeedVerticalPosition?() ?? CGVector()
    }
 }
```

and

```
protocol JoyStickDelegate: class {
      var objPhysicsBody: SKPhysicsBody? {get}
      var onJoysticNeedVerticalPosition: (()-> CGVector)? {get set}
}
```

then

```
class JoyStick: SKSpriteNode {
    ...
    init () {
    self.delegate?.onJoysticNeedVerticalPosition = {[weak self] in
            self?.getPositionVelocity()
        }
    }
    ...
    func getPositionVelocity() -> CGVector {
        guard let handlePosition = self.handle?.position else { return CGVector() }
        return CGVector(dx: handlePosition.x, dy: handlePosition.y)
    }
}
```

So in fact it is still two different objects, but the first one (GameScene) hold the closure with calculation logic, that in fact calculated in second one (JoyStick), and second one give it in detail to the first one by using delegate method.

Comment: Thank you but this is a confusion solution that doesn't really need to use the delegate pattern as it could simply reference the `self.joyStick?.getPositionVelocity()` as shown in my second solution. The goal is to move away from dropping this sort of logic in one centralized `didApplyConstraints()` in `GameScene`, instead I'm searching for a way to completely encapsulate it in the given SKSpriteNode like `joyStick` with the delegate pattern.